# ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES JSON in EclipseLink MOXy Dynamic ObjectGraphs

Tags: java, json, jaxb, eclipselink

Are there any properties like:

> JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES

or

> JsonGenerator.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES

Equivalent for:

> org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties

My question is because, I'm trying to get a JSON Output using Jackson with this approach:

```
private static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

static {
 om.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
 om.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
 om.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
 om.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
 om.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
}



try{
 String exp = om.writeValueAsString(customer);
 exp = "CREATE (customerNode"+customer.hashCode()+":CUSTOMER " + exp + " )";
}catch (Exception ex){}
```

At the end, I'm getting this exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "rootParentDescriptor": org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.InheritancePolicy#getRootParentDescriptor(0 params) vs org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.InheritancePolicy#isRootParentDescriptor(0 params) (through reference chain: blog.objectgraphs.dynamic.Customer["propertiesMap"]->java.util.HashMap["shippingAddress"]->org.eclipse.persistence.internal.dynamic.PropertyWrapper["value"]->blog.objectgraphs.dynamic.Address["type"]->org.eclipse.persistence.internal.dynamic.DynamicTypeImpl["descriptor"]->org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLDescriptor["inheritancePolicy"])
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:740)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddSerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:39)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._findAndAddDynamic(BeanPropertyWriter.java:463)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:441)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:262)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:186)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:23)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2575)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2097)
        at blog.objectgraphs.dynamic.DemoRuntime.main(DemoRuntime.java:86)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "rootParentDescriptor": org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.InheritancePolicy#getRootParentDescriptor(0 params) vs org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.InheritancePolicy#isRootParentDescriptor(0 params)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getGetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:167)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getAccessor(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.removeIgnorableTypes(BeanSerializerFactory.java:705)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanProperties(BeanSerializerFactory.java:562)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.constructBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:434)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:347)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:291)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:735)
        ... 26 more
```

Comment: What is your source "JSON" (if we can call it that), what is the code of the class you are trying to serialize?

Comment: @fge, for the specific case it's not an explicit class, the class is being generated automatically by the library from a XML source, as: blog.objectgraphs.dynamic.Customer, you can see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/04/moxys-object-graphs-dynamic-jaxb.html  for details about all previous processes

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink MOXy does not currently have a feature that enables you to have unquoted field names in JSON.  You can enter an enhancement request for this feature here:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink